# Attach form field in Activiti Enterprise

Tags: forms, activiti

I am trying to design a medium complex workflow.
In the workflow final stage, the assignee needs to upload an attachment of any type.

I have added `Attach` form field in the workflow form.
I validated the entire workflow, and there were no errors in the workflow and forms.

But, when I tried to publish the workflow, it says

> the workflow contains validation errors

I couldnt spot the problem.
I created a simple workflow with `Attach` form field and it works fine!!

However, `Attach` field doesn’t work in my medium complex workflow which contains various types of other form fields such as dropdown, display value, radio button, multiline textbox, dynamic table in the same form.

Can you please tell me whether adding other form fields hamper adding `Attach` form field?

Answer (score 0):

It can be due to id conflict. Different form fields must have different IDs. Since the built in form editor creates id based on label. Check if ids ae not same else it will throw a validation error. To solve this - check the over ride checkbox and provide a new id.